# SQLite3: select columns from multiple tables by many IDs

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose there are three tables: **A**, **B** and **C**. Each has *id* column (*INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY*) and *data* column (*TEXT*). There is also another table - **records** - with fields:

```
record_id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
a_id       INTEGER,
b_id       INTEGER,
c_id       INTEGER,
...
```

How to select **A**.*data*, **B**.*data* and **C**.*data* for a certain record (`record_id = <some value>`) by *a_id*, *b_id* and *c_id* accordingly when the latter can be either valid IDs or zeros (so each column in the result can be a TEXT value or `NULL`)?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results in a *text table* would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Sample data, following is my query using left joins-

```
select r.record_id,
       a.text as a_txt,
       b.text as b_txt,
       c.text as c_txt
  from records r
left join tablea a
        on r.a_id=a.id
left join tableb b
        on r.b_id=b.id
left join tablec c
        on r.c_id=c.id
where r.record_id=<Some Value>;
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Damn, www.w3schools.com documentation sucks. I didn't know that you can have several JOIN clauses.

Comment: Great, no worries!